# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'exampleFileMapper' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-batch, javabeans

I'm trying to implement an example of spring batch 2.1.9
the scenario is to have a flexibility to switch Writers based on some conditions.

i have one csv file as input and 4 csv file as output.

while runing my processor this error is occured

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'exampleFileMapper' is defined.
```

The problem is in this bean

```
<bean id="exampleFileSourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
<property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['file']}" />
<property name="lineMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <!-- split it -->
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">

                    <!-- this is missing --> 
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>

                    <property name="names" value="institution,type,nom,rubrique,montantPaye,MontantRetenu" />


            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <!-- map to an object -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">

                <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="exampleFileMapper" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

If anyone can explain to me what the operation of this line

```
<property name="prototypeBeanName" value="exampleFileMapper" />
```

Comment: you need to have a bean declaration with bean name (id) as exampleFileMapper

Comment: thank u for ur reply